# Why does an implicit email Intent work without specifying an IntentFilter?

Tags: android, android-intent

I created an email app using implicit email Intent:

[image]

I know that I need to add `Filter` In the manifest file. It worked with these filters.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"></action>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"></data>
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
</intent-filter>
```

My question is, why does it is still work well when removing the `intent-filter`?. I am not able to understand why it is working without any filter information.
The Android documentation says:

> To pass this filter, the action specified in the Intent must match one
> of the actions listed in the filter. If the filter does not list any
> actions, there is nothing for an intent to match, so all intents fail the test. However, if an Intent does not specify an
> action, it passes the test as long as the filter contains at least one
> action

Answer (score 0):

The code in the linked image is similar to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:ejemplo@ejemplo.com"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "asunto de prueba");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "probando el envio");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"suppport@ourcompany.com"});
startActivity(intent);
```

The reason it works is because Intent.ACTION_SENDTO is a generic "non explicit" intent supported by many apps on the Android device. These apps like GMail for example already contain an activity with an intent filter that handles the `android.intent.action.SENDTO` action.

If you are writing an email app or another app capable of sending a message then your app should should consider supporting this intent action as well.

If on the other hand, your goal is only to allow the user to send an email then it is unnecessary since there are already many apps on the Android device capable of sending an email. Further, the user would most likely prefer to choose their own email app for such as task.